# Swift 4 How to force Xcode to render vector images?

Tags: image, rendering, ios11, xcode9, vector-graphics

I am writing the app using latest Swift 4.1.2 and Xcode 9.4.1 for iOS 11.4. So I want to use vector images in my app in PDF format. I made the simple app which showing the problem, please, look:

[image]
This app only show only one image, but if you rotate the screen, rendering happens and picture becomes beautiful.

So the question is: how to force Xcode render vector images in Main.storyboard without touching the code? So app upload already rendered images?

Answer (score 0):

Go to -> Images.xcassets and select the image. From the attributes inspector, make sure that **preserve vector data** is checked as following:

[image]

I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thank you, but I already checked all this options... Maybe, there should be another way...

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 9 changes situation for vector data by allowing you to choose to treat the image as a vector at runtime. This means the image can smoothly scale to arbitrary sizes. The only change you need to make is to tick Preserve Vector Data for the PDF image in the asset catalog.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this method is not working. If you see, another answer is the same. It is strange, it is not working only on iPhone 7 or iPhone 5s.